# Shell script to combine three files using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have three files G_P_map.txt, G_S_map.txt and S_P_map.txt. I have to combine these three files using awk. The example contents are the following -

(G_P_map.txt contains)

```
test21g|A-CZ|1mos
test21g|A-CZ|2mos
 ...
```

(G_S_map.txt contains)

```
nwtestn5|A-CZ
nwtestn6|A-CZ
 ...
```

(S_P_map.txt contains)

```
3mos|nwtestn5
4mos|nwtestn6
```

Expected Output :

```
1mos, 3mos
2mos, 4mos
```

Here is the code which I tried. I was able to combine the first two, but I couldn't do along with the third one.

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR {file1[$1]=$1; next} {$2=file[$1]; print}' G_S_map.txt S_P_map.txt
```

Any ideas/help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both lines in the first file contain A-CZ. What is the key that links to nwtestn5/6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU AWK (`gawk`) 4 has `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` which would be perfect for this. However, the `gawk` manual includes a function that will provide this functionality for most versions of AWK.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    FS = "|"
}

function beginfile(ignoreme) {
    files++
}

function endfile(ignoreme) {
    # endfile() would be defined here if we were using it
}

FILENAME != _oldfilename \
{
    if (_oldfilename != "")
        endfile(_oldfilename)
    _oldfilename = FILENAME
    beginfile(FILENAME)
}

END   { endfile(FILENAME) }

files == 1 {    # save all the key, value pairs from file 1
    file1[$2] = $3
    next
}

files == 2 {    # save all the key, value pairs from file 2
    file2[$1] = $2
    next
}

files == 3 {    # perform the lookup and output
    print file1[file2[$2]], $1
}    

# Place the regular END block here, if needed. It would be in addition to the one above (there can be more than one)
```

Call the script like this:

```
./scriptname G_P_map.txt G_S_map.txt S_P_map.txt
```

Comment: NICE!  I looked at this question for a good 5 minutes and came up with no good way to pull the data into arrays.  Dennis, you've taught me something new about Awk *again*.  Thanks!  :-)

Comment: @ghoti: I fixed a couple of issues that would cause error messages.

Comment: You can replace the `FILENAME !=  _oldfilename` block with the simpler `FNR == 1{files++}`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: True, but I presented the more general solution that could be expanded upon if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at a combination of [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) and [cut](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut).

Comment: From [the ABCs of Unix](http://ifaq.wap.org/computers/abcsofunix.html): *J is for `join`, which nobody uses*. But it is exactly the right tool here! ^__^